# How to index a table for fast intersection?

Tags: data-structures, database-theory

For example (and this is not my use case), imagine there is a set of 50 000 random natural numbers represented in decimal with 8 digits (in the range 00 000 000 to 99 999 999). We could index the set with an index for each digit position (i.e. an array of pointers to all numbers ordered by their fist digit, another one ordered by the second digit, etc.). Imagine we wanted to know what numbers are in the list with at most 2 digits differing from 01 234 567.

We could start by finding the combinations of positions where the digits could differ. Then, for each combination, we could search the set for numbers with all the digits equal to 01 234 567 except for the 2 digits we chose. While it is fast to find the set of numbers where the first digit is 0 thanks to the index, it is, AFAICT, very inefficient to intersect that set with the set of numbers where the second digit is 1, and it is more efficient to directly check what numbers that start with 0 also match the rest of the condition. This is also not very efficient since it only reduces the search space to around one tenth of the entire set. In this case, we only need to do this search 3 times with 3 different indexes since any combination of 3 positions will never be completely covered by the combination of 2 positions where the digits could differ, but it's still quite slow.

For my use case:

- The number of "digits" is variable but less than 30
- The number of "digits" which can be different can be any number from 0 to the number of "digits"
- There are around 400k "numbers" in total
- The smaller the search time and memory/storage usage, the better.

Is there any way to perform the intersection efficiently? Or is there a more appropriate data structure for indexing the list?

Comment: Might be a solution to your problem: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/95665/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49148/755

Comment: @D.W. My bad, I meant to write "set" instead of "list". I will edit the question now. Also, thanks for the links. I will take a look at those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name that I normally use for this is "Hamming distance search".

So... 50,000 numbers isn't that many, and probably the simplest solution is to store them in a trie. Hamming distance search on a trie is extremely easy: you conceptually traverse all paths in the trie, pruning when the Hamming distance between the query and the path exceeds the threshold (2 in your case).

Note that if the key is a number (as it is in your case), each node in the trie represents a *range* of numbers. So if you had a data structure which queries intervals (i.e. it tells you how many numbers are in the set that are between two given query numbers), you can essentially do the same type of search that you would do on a trie. A rank/select index would be appropriate here, but even a sorted array with binary search might be efficient enough on 50,000 numbers.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. The only downside I can think of is that the search time grows exponentially with the hamming distance threshold.

Comment: That's unavoidable because the possible number of answers grows exponentially with the Hamming distance threshold.

Comment: By the way, you may be interested in this paper which solves a very similar problem with DNA sequences using rank/select indexes. https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/28/12/i172/269972

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed any constraints on the amount of space used, so a simple solution is to build ${8 \choose 2} = 28$ indices.  Each index lets you find whether a number is in the set, based on the value of 6 of the 8 digits.  Each index could be stored as a hashtable, that given a 6-digit number (the value of the digits in those 6 positions) tells you whether that number is in the set; or it could be stored as a sorted array, with lookups done by binary search.

This enables fast lookup.  Given a 8-digit number like 01234567, you enumerate over all 28 possibilities for the pair of digits that might differ, and look it up in each index.  This requires 28 index lookups, which should be very fast.

There are more sophisticated solutions available, e.g., if you have very long strings, but this might be good enough for the parameters you list.

Comment: I should have included more information in my question from the start. Unfortunately, this strategy is not viable for my use case, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With 8 digits you can probably use a 8-dimensional index where you assign one digit to every dimension. You also need a custom distance function.

Let's assume you want all numbers with 3 differing digits.

On the 8-dimensional index you can perform a nearest neighbor search. This will first return numbers with one differing digit, then all with two differing digits, and so on. You simply discard all numbers with < 3 differing digits and  stops once you you get 4 differing digits. This should give you all number with 3 differing digits.

You need a distance function that works like this:

```
double distance(double[] p1, double[] p2) {
   double sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < p1.length; ++i) {
      if (p1[i] != p2 [i]) {
         ++sum;
      }
   }
   return sum;
}
```

In effect the distance depends only on whether the digit differs, not on how much it differs.

The lookup time should be something like $O(dim * log(n) * r)$ with $n=50000$ and $r$ the result size (=number of matching entries).

Note that there is the "curse of dimensionality", so this approach will become less efficient with increasing dimensionality. You are probably fine with up to 100 digits (=dimensions) or so.

Comment: How could I implement nearest neighbor search efficiently with that distance function? I don't think k-d trees would work.

Comment: I think kd-trees should work. Why do you think they should not work?  You could also try R-trees, or my very own [PH-tree](http://phtree.org), I think they may be more efficient than kd-trees.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've edited the question to ask about a more general case.  There are two techniques worth knowing about: nearest neighbor search with the Hamming distance, and [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).

A locality-sensitive hash $H$ is one where, if $x,y$ are close to each other, then there is a good chance that $H(x)=H(y)$.  Then you can build several hashtables, each indexed using a different locality-sensitive hash, and containing all 50,000 items in your set; to test whether there is any item in the set near $x$, you look up $x$ in each hashtable using the appropriate hash.   In this case, we want "close" to be measured in Hamming distance.  There is [a very simple locality-sensitive hash function for the Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing#Bit_sampling_for_Hamming_distance).  In particular, we pick a random subset of the digit positions; then the hash of a number is the values of the digits in those positions.  If two numbers differ in only a few digit positions, then with good probability, they will have the same hash.  By repeating this with multiple hashtables, we have an extremely high probability of detecting any match.

I don't know much about data structures for nearest neighbor search with the Hamming distance, but you could do a literature search to see what is known.  See also [Using k-NN for Exact Match in Hamming Space (after Multi-index Hashing)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/64621/755).  You might also look at [metric trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tree) to see if they can be adapted for your situation.

That said, these problems become very hard if the allowable Hamming distance is large, so don't expect too much if you want to find matches with a large number of digits that differ.